# jquery ajax, getJSON gives null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function with it i want to get value from a php file:

```
var phrases = null;
function setPhrases(lang) {
    $.getJSON(locationHostname()+'json?json=lang&lang='+lang,
            function(json) {
        phrases = json;
        alert( 1 + ' ' + phrases);//phrases = [object Object]
    });
    alert( 2 + ' ' + phrases);//phrases = null
}
setPhrases('en');
alert(3+' '+phrases);//phrases = null
```

how to set correctly it, that alert(3+' '+phrases); gets an object instead of null? I want to use the function that e.g returns the value from getJSOn.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous , that's why you get undefined: the `alerts` are executed while ajax call is still running

You could call a function on success event, passing the `json` as argument, e.g.

```
function setPhrases(lang) {
    $.getJSON(locationHostname()+'json?json=lang&lang='+lang,
        function(json) {
            continueProcessing(json)
        }
    );
}

function continueProcessing(obj) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  `.getJSON` runs asynchronously, and unless it's lightning fast, the `alert(2)` and `alert(3)` will run before it completes.  You need to have the `alert(2)` and `alert(3)` as part of the success function, or use a `Deferred`.

EDIT: I guess since it's electronic it probably *is* lightning fast, and even that's not enough!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't get `phrases` in third `alert()` due to asynchronous behavior of `$.getJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a callback method. the problem with your getJSON method that it's async.

example:

```
function setPhrases(lang, callback) {
    $.getJSON(locationHostname()+'json?json=lang&lang='+lang,
            function(json) {

        callback(json);
    });
}

   setPhrases('en',function(result) {

    alert(result);

});
```